# loop for Principal Component Analysis does not work

Tags: r, for-loop, pca

I have two dataframes

```
df1 <- data.frame(item1 = c("5", "8", "2"), item2 = c("2", "2", "6"), item3 = c("4", "78", "76"))

df2 <- data.frame(item1 = c("54", "82", "12"), item2 = c("6", "7", "87"), item3 = c("3", "8", "7"))
```

I want to perform a PCA in a loop like this

```
list <- as.list(c(df1,df2))
for(item in list){
  pca <- PCA(item)
pca_individuel <- fviz_pca_ind(pca, pointsize = "cos2", 
             pointshape = 21, fill = "cos2",
             repel = TRUE, # Avoid text overlapping (slow if many points)
             geom = "point", # no text only points
             title = "PCA of food"
             )
View(pca_individuel) }
```

It shows this error:

> Error in facto_summarize(X, element = element, axes = axes, result = summary.res) : The value of the argument axes is incorrect. The number of axes in the data is: 1. Please try again with axes between 1 - 1

Who can spot my mistake? I appreciate every trial.

I thank you in advance
IT-girl

Comment: Try `list = list(df1, df2)` instead of `as.list(c(df1, df2))`. When you use `c()` on data frames, it generalizes them to lists of their columns and concatenates, so you end up with one list containing the columns from each of the data frames. This makes sense with your error message because when you iterate, you are iterating over each column one at a time

Comment: Thank you, as well for your explanation